# JSON Parsing errors with RESTeasy/JAXB

Tags: java, json, rest, jaxb, resteasy

I'm trying to make a call to the iTunes REST service that returns information about the genres defined in iTunes via a RESTeasy client.  The JSON object returned by this call looks something like this:

```
{
   "35":{
      "name":"iPod Games",
      "id":"35",
      "url":"https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/ipod-games/id35"
   },
   "36":{
      "name":"App Store",
      "id":"36",
      "url":"https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/ios/id36?mt=8"
   }
}
```

I've defined my response object model like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ITunesGenre implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4330727214147295490L;

    @XmlElement
    private String name = null;

    @XmlElement
    private String id = null;

   ...

}
```

However, when I make the call via my RESTeasy client, however, I get serialization errors.  I believe it is due to the fact that this is not a true List or array of objects.  Instead, it seems like each entry has an "identifier" on it (in the example above, the "35" or "36").

Given a JSON object like this, how do I map this so that the RESTeasy client can deserialize it?  I've not encountered objects of this format before.  I obviously can't hard-code each identifier, since there will be several and they could potentially change.

You can see the full JSON object returned by this call (it's sizable) by [clicking here](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/genres).  You'll see that this object structure is found throughout this object, rather than using simple Lists or Arrays of objects.

Any ideas?  I'd really appreciate any help you can give.

Comment: Please post exact error message you got on the server?

Comment: I'm afraid this cannot be expressed with JAXB. I'd take `org.json.JSONObject`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response is a Map so root element is not your ITunesGenre class but the Map.I suppose that it is clear how to modify response object.

Comment: That was it.  I changed the return object on the client to Map<String, Object> and it worked like a charm.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it could look something like this (though i haven't tested it)

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Response implements Serializable
{
    public Response(){
    }

    private java.util.Map<String, Genre> genres = new java.util.HashMap<String, Genre> ();
}


public class Genre implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4330727214147295490L;

    public Genre(){
    }

    @XmlElement
    private String name = null;

    @XmlElement
    private String id = null;

   ...

}
```